# How do I extract a background from a Windows 7 Theme file?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, extract

Pretty obvious, How do I extract a background from a Windows 7 Theme file?

I like the background pics from some of the themes I've downloaded, but is there anyway I can get the pictures (background images) by themselves?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the Personalization Control Panel save the theme for sharing as a .themepack file - right click on the current theme and choose "Save theme for sharing". Then open the saved themepack file with [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or similar and extract the images you want.

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: Works fine for me, 7zip 9.20 in Windows 8.1.  Right click on .themepack file and choose 7zip > Extract...

Comment: This still works. A theme pack is essentially a CAB with a different extension. Most archiver should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 6):

You can find those wallpapers on your C drive after you install a theme

Navigate to

`C:\Users\(your user name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`

Comment: This no longer works either. All I see at that location are `.theme` files which can't be extracted.

Comment: Works for me, but mine were in Roaming instead of Local. Try navigating to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes` instead

Answer (score 4):

**with 7-Zip,** 
1) right click the file, select **Open archive**
 
2) open DesktopBackground folder
 
3) select the wallpaper you want or select all by mouse pointer, then click on **extract** option

now check your extracted location

Answer (score 1):

You first have to save the theme for sharing which will save as a ".themepack" file. Then you can open it as an archive as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

In the Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Desktop Background under personalisation.
Right click the required image and select Propeties
Location is where it is.
Works for me on W7 Home Premium

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows 7:

1.) Go to your desktop,right click, select Personalize.

2.) Select Desktop Background on the bottom left of the window.

3.) Click select all then right click and select preview.

```
The windows photo viewer will pop up with the pictures.
```

4.) There Select file, select  Make a Copy..., select your folder you want to save it too, click save.

5.) Hit right arrow key and do the same process for the next pic.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with Windows 10 theme packs. If it doesn't work, make sure that you have already installed 7-Zip or equivalent so that option is available when you right-click.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this duplicates information already provided in [another answer by Sim](http://superuser.com/a/134655/461558)

Answer (score 0):

Directions for  how to use themes not compatible with Windows 7:

1. Download MS theme from website.  Filetype will be *.deskthemepack

   It doesn't matter where you save it, but to keep it all together save it here:

   ```
   C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes
   ```

   The file will not be assigned to any program to open.
2. Open the unknown file in an archive program like 7zip. Extract files to a folder you can name with the same name as the themepack.
3. Go back into Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Personalization.
4. Double-click on Desktop background and then browse to the folder where you saved the images. Your new theme images are loaded and now work, but are unsaved.
5. Select any other customized settings, like Sounds, etc.
6. Double-click on the "unsaved theme" in the my themes lists and it will prompt you to save the images as a compatible *.theme file.
7. Now you can go back into your themes and launch the theme by double-clicking on the name you saved it as.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question which is about WIndows 7 themes not incompatible themes.

Answer (score 0):

navigate to:
C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper

All the jpgs for the themes are saved here. Copy your preferred pictures or point your screensaver to this directory.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the theme file with a zip extension and unzipped it with winrar and got all the images extracted.